# Can i use RouteLink to change the parameter of the route depending on link clicked, MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

In Global.asax.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Menu", PageName="Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "NewRoute", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{PageName}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Menu", PageName = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I want this parameter `PageName` to be "`Index`" only for the first Home page loading. After that on menu link click i need to transfer the value of parameter `PageName` corresponding to the link and not the value "Index".Hence i wrote a new MapRoute, where PageName is optional and not "index".

So in my `_Layout.cshtml`

```
foreach(...)
{
     @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Menu", "Home", new { PageName = item.PageName, role = "Admin" }, null)

}
```

Currently for all link click only the parameter value "Index" is taken, Which is unintended. I want this 'index' to be 'home' or 'aboutUS' or ''... depending on the link user clicks.

After some search, i found that RouteLink can change the default route...

```
 @Html.RouteLink(item.Title, "NewRoute", new { PageName = item.PageName })
```

In effect, i need to specify a defaultvalue for PageName and also it should change on link clicks.

Please tell me whether routelink is the solution for this issue.

Comment: do you need the {id} ?

Comment: no id is not a required parameter...

Comment: Please give your question a well readable title.

Comment: Yes, "routelink" its definitely the solutions

Comment: @hiddenbyte: Please post your comment as an answer. When i replaced the  {Id} with {PageName} in MapRoute, it began to take parameters depending on link click. Thanks.

Comment: RouteLink was not at all required for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Global.asax.cs, change the {ID} to {PageName}

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{pagename}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Menu", PageName="Index" } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

No need to add a new route and also RouteLink is not required. ActionLink itself works.